# How can I move this table to the left in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have a DT data table in my RMarkdown document that allows users to download to a csv. How can I shift this table to the left in my HTML file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to get the whole document to shift left, you can add inline CSS code in your Rmarkdown, like this

````
---
title: "DT table"
author: "Daniel"
date: "5/22/2021"
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>


```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```
````

Which renders in the web browser all the way to the left.
[image]

If you know more CSS than me, then you can control your document with Divs and CSS selectors to get a even more specific layout

Comment: This does the trick, yeah I figured it was something in HTML but dont know HTML too well, thank you